# Javascript .replace() same character different outcome

Tags: javascript, css, replace

I have a word : **google**, and I'm changing each character to a specific color, but I can't figure out how to make letters "o" different colors

This is my JS:

```js
var text = $("#typed-strings").html().replace(/e/g, '<span class="red">e</span>').replace(/g/g, '<span class="blue">g</span>').replace(/l/g, '<span class="green">l</span>').replace(/o/g, '<span class="yellow">o</span>');
$("#typed-strings").html(text);
```

```css
.red {
  color: rgb(219, 50, 54);
}
.blue {
  color: rgb(72, 133, 237);
}
.green {
  color: rgb(60, 186, 84);
}
.yellow {
  color: rgb(244, 194, 13);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="typed-strings">google</div>
```

maybe someone has ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT:

Thanks everyone for such a rich response, my question was edited by a moderator, perhaps that's why you've seen some changes.
I uploaded this tryout on heroku, to make things easier, but yeah, I have this long text, and every time letter "o" shows up I'd like it to either be, red or yellow, html doesn't really matter since it's purely for visualisation, but I've learned a lot from the conversations - thanks!
that's the app:
https://googlefonts.herokuapp.com

EDIT 2: 
also added the non-working version within the page

Comment: Your HTML please?

Comment: Is text even set before the html assignment executes...?

Comment: I see you want specific colors for specific letters, what is the rule of assigning colors when a letter is found multiple times?

Comment: The issue is that you are replacing globally, and as you add classes there are more characters added that get replaced, so you get incoherent and invalid HTML.

Comment: That is a bad bad way to replace. You will end up matching the strings inside the tags you just added.

Comment: If you insist on doing it that way with replacing - you can modify the regular expression to match second, third and so on characters: `/(?!o)o/` lookup non-capturing regular expression groups.

Comment: This is a very special case. If you do not expect any other values other than "google", there is no point in finding a very elegant solution for this really, because the output is already determined in the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have pointed out your issue is that you are replacing `g` with 
`<span class="...">g</span>` 
then replacing all l's in the last string which replaces the l in class.

Another way around this is to use a function for replace. While using a function each match is replaced in turn and any replacements you make are ignored.

Besides that you can use a separate key and boolean to track whether you have replaced the first o already or not. I added this to my example using the boolean as part of the replacement-key for the letter `o` to simplify things.

```js
var replacements = {
  g: '<span class="blue">g</span>',
  o0: '<span class="red">o</span>',
  o1: '<span class="yellow">o</span>',
  l: '<span class="green">l</span>',
  e: '<span class="red">e</span>'
};

var ele = $("#typed-strings");
var text = ele.html();

var firstODone = false;
text = text.replace(/[gogle]/g, function (letter) {
  var key = letter;
  if (key === 'o') {
    key = key + (+firstODone); //Convert the boolean to an integer, 0 or 1
    firstODone = true;
  }
 
  return replacements[key];
})
  
 ele.html(text);
```

```css
.red {
  color: rgb(219, 50, 54);
}
.blue {
  color: rgb(72, 133, 237);
}
.green {
  color: rgb(60, 186, 84);
}
.yellow {
  color: rgb(244, 194, 13);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="typed-strings">google</div>
```

If you only needed jQuery for this you can easily get rid of it, too. You can use 
`var ele = document.getElementById("typed-strings");`
to get your element and 
`ele.innerHTML`
to get and set your html to the element.
e.g.: `ele.innerHTML = text`

Comment: Thank you, I didnt notice that :)

Comment: I think that OP wants two different 'o' letters - that's the point of question.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it's very elegant and logical, but unfortunately it breaks my code, I forgot to mention that I'm animating the letters, with another library, and perhaps that is making things more difficult.. 
The error that I'm receiving is this: TypeError: undefined is not an object evaluating ('text.replace') I've added a link to the website in my original question if that helps

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use the following regex:

```
letter + '{1}(?![^<]*\>)'
```

The above will replace only lowercase single letter G-s that are not inside a tag `<>`, here is an example:

```js
function replaceWithSpanClass( string, letter, className ){
  var regex = new RegExp( letter + '{1}(?![^<]*\>)', 'g' );
  return string.replace( regex, '<span class="' + className + '">' + letter + '</span>')
}

var text = 'google';
text = replaceWithSpanClass( text, 'g', 'red' );
text = replaceWithSpanClass( text, 'o', 'blue' );
text = replaceWithSpanClass( text, 'l', 'yellow' );
text = replaceWithSpanClass( text, 'e', 'green' );

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = text;
```

```css
.yellow { color: yellow; }
.green { color: green; }
.blue { color: blue; }
.red { color: red; }
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

In this case it means that a class like `yellow` does not get its `o` replaced by `<span class="blue">o</span>`. That way you are sure you are *only* modifying outside your nodes.

Comment: I think there are better ways than using regex to try to match non-html strings.

Comment: @Marie Feel free to post about them. And on that note, you are using Regex as well, and you are solving the same problem in a different way. But yeah, downvote, if your count looks higher it will probably get ticked.

Comment: I dont mind regex, but your answer uses regex to parse html which is rarely a good idea.

Comment: I think that OP wants two different 'o' letters - that's the point of question.

Comment: @Marie, to be honest, I agree when it comes to 'parsing HTML', but thats _not_ what I am doing here - I am simply ignoring HTML. I am not trying to read anything or find out anything, I'm just trying to make sure that I dont replace anything that might be essential.

Comment: The string is html and you are using regex to parse that html and ignore tags. It works in this case but if we teach people to do things this way they may again in the future where it might not work. I think it is best to avoid for beginners.

Comment: @Marie That sounds like a fine argument. Personally I'd argue against regex as well, but I had this one lying around and it worked so I thought it might help to see what the possibilities are.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering, i am able to use jQuery, and I tried Marie's version, but it changes only the first two o letters (one red, one yellow), the other ones that follow, are all yellow, maybe you could help me out?

Comment: @JurgisLietunovas You can replace this line: `key = key + (+firstODone);` with this one: `key = key  + (+(firstODone = !firstODone)); ` from Maries answer. Remove the next line (we don't want to reset it to `true` every time). It will flip the variable from `true` to `false` every iteration, and then convert it to either 0 or 1, therefor switching the value from red to blue every time. Does that help?

Comment: yes! damn, i was trying to fix this for hours, going into all those regex details, thinking of setting up more loops and so on, and the solution was so simple, thanks so much! https://googlefonts.herokuapp.com just wondering why is it slowing down on coloured letters so much

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(() => {
    let oldStr = $("#typed-strings").html();
    let newStr = '';

    for(let i = 0; i < oldStr.length; i++) {
        if (oldStr[i] === 'g') {
            newStr += '<span class="blue">g</span>'
        } else if (oldStr[i] === 'o') {
            newStr += '<span class="yellow">o</span>'
        }
        // Add other letters here
    }

    $("#typed-strings").html(newStr);
});


</script>
```

Comment: You might want to add an `else { newStr += oldStr[i] }`. Otherwise letters that you did not target will disappear.

Comment: He would need to use common sense and fill in where it says 'add other letters here' but you are correct. This was just a plain JS/JQuery way to do it without Regex's and such. There are slicker answers than mine already posted but figured I'd throw out a really simplistic straightforward one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that would return the color by the letter and use replace method with callback function like this:

```
var colors = {
    g: 'blue',
    o: 'yellow',
    l: 'green',
    e: 'red'
};
function wrapTheLetter(letter) {
    var colorClass = colors[letter];
    if (letter == 'o') {
        // update it's color for the future
        colors.o = 'grey';
    }
    return '<span class="' + colorClass + '">'+letter+'</span>';
}
var text = $("#typed-strings").html().replace(/\w/g, wrapTheLetter);
$("#typed-strings").html(text);
```

Comment: This was not what the OP was asking by a long shot. This is useful only _after_ the OP has solved the current problem. With the current problem, his spans were incorrect to begin with.

Comment: Updated. Is it better? :P

Comment: Yes? At least it does what the OP asked for :) Next time make sure to properly read the question and provide an appropriate solution, otherwise downvotes will come your way (not mine, I gave you time to realise).